# Are there multicellular isogamous species?

Tags: evolution, reproduction, natural-selection, sex, gamete

**Are there multicellular isogamous species?**

Seeking through the examples of [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogamy) I would tend to think that there are no multicellular isogamous species.

Comment: "Isogamy is common among algae, lower fungi, and many protozoans (Rhizopoda, Radiolaria, and lower Gregarinida) but absent in multicellular animals. In isogamy the copulating gametes differ in their biochemical and physiological properties." - but this is not from a scientific article...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Our knowledge about the sexual transmission of mitochondria and
>   plastids (hereafter organelles) in isogamous eukaryotes comes mostly
>   from studies of the yeast Saccharomyces cerevisiae and the green alga
>   Chlamydomonas reinhardtii which are both unicellular species. To
>   investigate organelle inheritance in a multicellular organism with
>   morphological isogamy, we studied the filamentous brown alga
>   Ectocarpus siliculosus, in which each gamete contributes one plastid
>   and at least one mitochondrion to the zygote. ...

- 2004 - [Inheritance of organelles in artificial hybrids of the isogamous multicellular chromist alga Ectocarpus siliculosus (Phaeophyceae)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09670260410001683241#.VEP16RaWdqQ)

So it is possible, but it seems like very rare.